# how to add a library to the dependencies gradle of LIBGDX project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

All is in the question , I've tried all the answers I found in SO and others sites but with no luck , this is what I've tried so far :

adding `compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')` to my build.gradle

adding `compile files('lib/tween-engine-api-sources.jar')` to build.gradle

the library I want to add is **[Tween engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/)** .

build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'my-gdx-game'
        gdxVersion = '1.5.4'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
        ashleyVersion = '1.3.1'
        aiVersion = '1.5.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")

        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"


    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"

        compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: Please add the error you get to your question.

Comment: Are you developing this on Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the wiki article [Dependency management with Gradle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle), you can find all the information you need. There's even an extra part about the Tween Engine.

Your approach should work, however, you need to update Eclipse via a `Right-Click on your projects -> Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies`.

For me it worked better though to install the dependencies in my local repository and then reference it from there, instead of referencing the lib folder. This is described [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#mavenizing-local-dependencies).