# How to import the Kryonet library to a libGdx project on Android Studio

Tags: java, libgdx, android-studio-2.0, kryonet, android-studio-import

How do you add an external library (in this case, kryonet) to a libGdx project in Android Studio? I've seen people telling it's related to the build.grade, but where do you put the jar file or how do you import it?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253612/how-to-add-a-library-to-the-dependencies-gradle-of-libgdx-project

Comment: That one talks about Tween Engine, isn't the process a little diferent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the "build.gradle (Project : projectname)" file, under "project(":core") { dependencies {" add this line:
`compile "com.esotericsoftware:kryonet:2.22.0-RC1"`
Android studio will prompt you for gradle sync, do it, after it's done you can now call the kryonet classes. Happy days :-)

Comment: In doing that I get an error message saying: "Failed to resolve: kryonet:kryonet:2.21", and I guess it's because of the kryonet location?
Where do I need to put the Kryonet folder really?

Comment: Sorry about that, that was written based on kryonet's documentation (which was wrong) - use this line instead in the same location: compile "com.esotericsoftware:kryonet:2.22.0-RC1. You don't need to manually download / place any files, gradle automatically downloads the dependencies you declare.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!
But is it always so complicated to add external libraries to Android Studio?

Comment: Alright! Yeah it takes a bit of getting used to working with gradle, you'll find it gets easier with time. Could you accept this as the correct answer? It helps to build up reputation points, which can be used to bounty a question I desperately need answered :-) Thanks.

Comment: It even worked for me. My core's build.gradle had delegated to the top level one so I was getting `Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()` until I figured out what to do. And kryonet is showing the most recent commit from Nathan Sweet so looks worth adding.

Comment: compile "com.esotericsoftware: kryonet: 2.22.0-RC1 That helped. But how do you know this?